# BeautifulSoup double layer

Tags: python, parsing, loops, beautifulsoup

I'm building a little module which has the task of doing the following things:
-Read a webpage (cavirtex.com/orderbook)
-Get with urllib the source and open it with beautifulsoup
-parse and get the `body.div(id='xx')`
now, I'm stuck here. I want to re-beautifulsoup the result and iterate over two rows of td inside of the bigger tr and get the values and sum them. If someone knows how to do that, please explain it to me because i've been stuck here for quite a few hours. Oh, and here is my source code:

```
myurl = urllib.urlopen('http://cavirtex.com/orderbook').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(myurl)

selling = soup.body.div(id ='orderbook_buy') 
selling = str(selling)
selling = BeautifulSoup(selling)
Sresult = selling.find_all(['tr'])
amount = 30
count = 0
cadtot = 0
locamount = 0
for rows in Sresult:
    #agarrar string especifico para vez
    Wresult = Sresult[count]
    #crear lista
    Eresult = [Wresult]
    Eresult = str(Eresult)
    cosito = str(Eresult[count])

    print cosito
    count = int(count) + 1
    cadtot = cadtot + locamount
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question, but if your goal is to download and process the orderbook from `cavirtex.com`, I recommend you use the chart API instead:

https://www.cavirtex.com/api/CAD/orderbook.json

That link has all the info you need in friendly JSON.

Example:

```
import urllib
import json

url = "https://www.cavirtex.com/api/CAD/orderbook.json"
orderbook_json = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
orderbook = json.loads(orderbook_json)

print(orderbook['bids'])
print(orderbook['asks'])
```

There's also:

https://www.cavirtex.com/api/CAD/trades.json

Most bitcoin exchanges support the same API, as documented by bitcoincharts.com: http://bitcoincharts.com/about/exchanges/

Enjoy!

Comment: Thank you for your data! it's very useful

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum the price and value in this table? This does just that and stores results as dictionary with ints from 1 to 21 as keys and sum of price and value in CAD as values. If you need some other output you can tweak it easily to fit your particular needs.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import *

myurl = urllib.urlopen('http://cavirtex.com/orderbook').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(myurl)

selling = soup.body.div(id ='orderbook_buy')
Sresult = selling[0].find_all(['tr'])
data = {}
c = 0
for item in Sresult:
    # You need to sum price and value? this sums up price and value
    tds = item.find_all(["td"])[2:]
    c += 1
    summa = 0
    for elem in tds:
        elemVal = float(elem.text.replace(" CAD", ""))
        summa += elemVal
        data[c] = summa
print data
```

This gives us:

```
 {2: 200.16001, 3: 544.5600000000001, 4: 543.072, 5: 6969.35103, 6: 1000.14005, 7: 108.601, 8: 472.95, 9: 533.26, 10: 180.0, 11: 271.34000000000003, 12: 178.0, 13: 242.94, 14: 334.85, 15: 176.0, 16: 320.08000000000004, 17: 1269.05023, 18: 1071.33022, 19: 2618.9202, 20: 97.12008999999999, 21: 656.48005}
```

Number 2 is 200.16001 which is equal to 90.76001 + 109.40, and so on...

Comment: Thank you Pawelmhm! It's just what I needed.